# How to move an SVG object along with path by using Framer Motion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, svg, framer-motion

I have an SVG object and a path.
**How can I move/run the object along with the PATH?**

This is an example of what I mean

[image]

I tried to find docs but didn't find any proper docs in Framer Motion.
I'm expecting a proper solution for my code.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Greensock GSAP to animate the circles.

```
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);

useEffect(() => {
  gsap.to("#circle1", {
    duration: 5,
    repeat: 12,
    repeatDelay: 3,
    yoyo: true,
    ease: "power1.inOut",
    motionPath: {
      path: "#path1",
      align: "#path1",
      autoRotate: true,
      alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5]
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Note: I added some IDs to the `circle` and `path` for each of use.